# Make of LinVst data not possible - wine problem

Tags: wine, 32-bit

So if I try to make the Makefile(s) in the LinVst folders I receive the following error:

```
    make
wineg++ -m32 lin-vst-server.wine32.o remotepluginserver.wine32.o paths.wine32.o -L/opt/wine-stable/lib/wine -L/opt/wine-devel/lib/wine -L/opt/wine-staging/lib/wine -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine-development -lpthread -lX11 -lrt -lshell32 -lole32  -o lin-vst-servertrack32.exe
/usr/bin/ld: relocatable linking with relocations from format elf64-x86-64 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/libwinecrt0.a(exe_entry.o)) to format elf32-i386 (lin-vst-servertrack32.pgy3gc.o) is not supported
winebuild: /usr/bin/ld failed with status 1
winegcc: /usr/lib/wine/winebuild failed
make: *** [Makefile:43: lin-vst-servertrack32.exe] Error 2
```

I tried to reinstall wine and to add i386 but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use 64-bit wine to build 32-bit code. Ensure that your wine installation has the 32bit packages installed in addition to the usual 64bit ones

Comment: I did install them via "sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386"

Comment: it:s all mentioned here https://github.com/osxmidi/LinVst/tree/master/Make-Guide and i tried to install everything but "wine-devel" couldn't been found.

Comment: You're in a Ubuntu forum. The 'wine-devel' line is under Fedora instructions on the page you just linked